# Web browser to WPF image drag and drop

Tags: c#, wpf, image, drag-and-drop, browser

I have a window set to allow drop and my Drop Event Handler is working fine for images dragged in from Windows Explorer.  But dragging in pictures from a web browser has some quirks.

In Firefox, I am only getting .bmp files with random names.  Images from IE 8 (haven't tested others) only show a Not Allowed mouse cursor.  I guess this is because IE has a security prompt when dragging images out into the Windows Explorer.

Has anyone come across a solution, perhaps browser-agnostic, for dragging images out of a web browser and into a WPF window?

Here's the current event handler:

```
private void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

            foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(droppedFilePath);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442085/receiving-an-image-dragged-from-web-page-to-wpf-window

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled on this problem with IE8. Can't waste time figuring it out right now, but setting the window's `PreviewDragEnter` and `PreviewDragOver` to the following handler seems to work around the "Not Allowed" cursor part of it at the moment:

```
    private void Window_PreviewDragEnterAndOver ( object sender , DragEventArgs e ) {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Link;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```